# Where to store or mount a fire extinguisher?

Tags: safety

I bought a small 1kg fire extinguisher for my car. However, I'm not sure where should I mount or store it. It should be readily available for emergencies, but at the same time it must not endanger anybody in the case of an accident.

Comment: My Opinion? Somewhere towards the center of the vehicle where you have easy access. Definitely mount it though, as leaving lie free (whether in the trunk/boot or in the cabin) is a bad thing. Preference is probably someplace not very visable. Again, this is opinion.

Comment: Make sure if you floor-mount it (as others have suggested) that you factor in the sliding (adjustable) seat position for everyone who will use the seat. For example, don't mount it right in front of the drivers seat only to find out your wife can't slide her seat forward any further because the extinguisher is blocking the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best place for it is on the floor, just in front of the passenger seat. It's easy to get to from the driver's seat and in the case of a head-on collision, the only way it can go is away from your girlfriend's/wife's pretty face. But definitely mount it. And buy a proper mount that was designed to allow you to easily remove it in case of an emergency. There's no time for fiddling with Allen keys or a socket wrench when stuff's on fire.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to mount it where you can reach it easily when there is a need. You can put it under the driver seat or in front of the passenger seat. In case, if you get into an accident, the extinguisher that was under your seat will be easily accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I mounted mine drivers side and level with the bed of my silverado also Larado bed cover helps keeps eyes off of it too

Comment: *near the tailgate not behind the cab

Answer (score 1):

Mine fits in the beverage holder between my front bucket seats.